# "followed" as a participial phrase

Tags: phrases, participial

Here's another participial phrase comma question (sorry, just trying to get this right).

"The doorbell rang twice followed by the sound of the lock disengaging in the front of the house."

Assume "followed by" is a participial phrase. Do I place a comma in front of it? It is not restrictive, yet the sentence would sound strange if the phrase was moved to the front of the sentence.

Comment: The "restrictive/non-restrictive" distinction only applies to relative clauses, which this isn't.

Answer (score 1):

*"The doorbell rang twice, **followed by the sound of the lock disengaging in the front of the house."***

The bolded is parenthetical, thus requires a comma in front.

And no, the fronted variant also sounds natural to me:

***Followed by the sound of the lock disengaging in the front of the house,"*** the doorbell rang twice.